# VBA Cells range address syntax (FIND specific value to LastColumn)

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a question regarding the error I am facing, since I can't seem to figure it out.
I have:

```vb
With Worksheets("Machine Specification")
  Range("C138", .Cells(Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, LastColumn)).Value = UserForm_ConnectionParameters.NormCurrent_ComboBox.Text
End With
```

Which I need to change to one that instead of `C138` will find the row based on it's value in
column `C`. So It seems to me that the code would be:

```vb
With Worksheets("Machine Specification")
  Cells(Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, 3), .Cells(Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, LastColumn)).Value = UserForm_ConnectionParameters.NormCurrent_ComboBox.Text
End With
```

And `VBA` returns a red line.

[image]

What is the mistake I'm making, can someone, please, help?

Comment: Can you explain what means: `And VBA returns a red line.`? Seems, you've putted a breakpoint... Use `F9` to switch of.

Comment: The second line of the code is displayed in red indicating that the line is written incorrectly.

Comment: The second line should start with a dot (".") and the same in `.Cells.Find(` in order to refer the respective sheet. Of course, `lastColumn` should exist and have a value > 1...

Comment: Nop, it still displays it red

Comment: What "Norm. Current (A)" is?

Comment: It's the specific cell value I am looking to find in the column

Comment: In "the column" or in all the sheet cells?

Comment: I have that specific value in column "B" somewhere. Code:: "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Phases").Row, 3).Select" selects the cell in column "C" next to the cell with theat specific value  wherever the cell with that value in column "B" may be

Comment: Don't chain things, you will get errors if you don't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range(Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, 3), Cells(Cells.Find("Lower Film Width (mm)").Row, LastColumn)).Select
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Range(.Cells(.Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, LastColumn)).value = UserForm_ConnectionParameters.NormCurrent_ComboBox.Text
```

But it looks easier:

```
iRow = .Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row
Range(.Cells(iRow, 3), .Cells(iRow, LastColumn)).value = UserForm_ConnectionParameters.NormCurrent_ComboBox.Text
```

Comment: This returns an error upon execution: Application defined or object defined error. Regarding the easier, it's not my case as I have to go through hundreds of such lines. I may batch change it once the "Harder" way works

Comment: Your first suggestion returns another error: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: @Eduards Corrected. Try this way.

Comment: There's still  Application defined or object defined error

Answer (score 1):

Your second example won't work as `Cells` references a single cell, while 'Range' can reference one or more cells.

I guess your line of code should be written as:

```
.Range(.Cells(.Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, LastColumn)) = UserForm_ConnectionParameters.NormCurrent_ComboBox.Text
```

The problem with that is, as @SJR commented, you're chaining commands that can fail together.  If "Norm. Current (A)" doesn't exist on the sheet you'll get an error message.

Also, your line of code only partially makes use of the `With` command.

```
Cells(Cells.Find("Norm. Current (A)").Row, 3), .Cells(Cells.Find
```

In the example above only the second from last `Cells` is looking at the *Machine Specification* sheet as it has the `.` before it.  All the other `Cells` are looking at whichever sheet is currently active - if it's not the correct sheet you'll get an error as you can't build a range reference that looks at different sheets.

I'd write the code as:

```
Sub Test()

    'Don't know where you get your LastColum figure from, so made it up.
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = 5
    
    Dim NormCurrentA As Range

    With Worksheets("Machine Specification")
        
        'Find remembers the last settings you used, so best to set them all.
        Set NormCurrentA = .Cells.Find( _
            What:="Norm. Current (A)", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=True)
            
        'Check that something was found before trying to use it.
        If Not NormCurrentA Is Nothing Then
        
            'All Ranges and Cells must be preceded by a '.' to work with the With....End With command.
            .Range(.Cells(NormCurrentA.Row, 3), .Cells(NormCurrentA.Row, LastColumn)) = UserForm_ConnectionParameters.NormCurrent_ComboBox.Text
            
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I kinda accidentally figured it out myself, but had no idea why it works all of a sudden. Thanks, friend!